# socket io, How can I get this data

Tags: express, socket.io

I am doing a chat with express js and I would like to have every usernames into an array. I work with socket.io 2.1.1.
The solution should be simple but I don't have any idea how to get access to a data in socket io.
Here is what I get when I do "console.log(io.sockets.clients());"

```
Namespace {
    name: '/',
        server:
    Server {...},
    sockets:
    { ...},
    connected:
    { K3xcxiIUErAEp7SsAAAA:
        Socket {
        nsp: [Circular],
            server: [Object],
            adapter: [Object],
            id: 'K3xcxiIUErAEp7SsAAAA',
            client: [Object],
            conn: [Object],
            rooms: [Object],
            acks: {},
        connected: true,
            disconnected: false,
            handshake: [Object],
            fns: [],
            flags: {},
        _rooms: [],
            _events: [Object],
            _eventsCount: 3,
            username: 'toto' },
        JGiA8j3MfQntUS0YAAAB:
            Socket {
        nsp: [Circular],
            server: [Object],
            adapter: [Object],
            id: 'JGiA8j3MfQntUS0YAAAB',
            client: [Object],
            conn: [Object],
            rooms: [Object],
            acks: {},
        connected: true,
            disconnected: false,
            handshake: [Object],
            fns: [],
            flags: {},
        _rooms: [],
            _events: [Object],
            _eventsCount: 3,
            username: 'titi' } },
    ... }
```

What I want are the usernames under "connected".
So I would like to have an array like : ["toto", "titi"].

Thank you for your help,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this--

From client side you send the username to the server

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect();
data = {name: userName};
socket.emit('data', data);
```

On the server side, you will receive the data, retrieve the username and store it in array.

Server side:

```
var users = [];
socket.on('data' function(data) {
    var userName = data.name;
    users.push(userName);
});
console.log(users);
```

Using  `io.sockets.clients()`-

As you can see that the connected in your `console.log` is an object and the keys of the objects are all the connected users. To extract that

```
var connectedUsers = Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).map(function(socketId) {
    return io.sockets.connected[socketId].username;
});

console.log(connectedUsers);
```

Comment: The thing is the data I put are already on the server. I have no need to send the username to the server since it is already on it.
Do you know a way that I can go throw  those data ?

Comment: The usernames on the server are the names of all the users who ever got connected??

Comment: My code sends the name of the users who got connected to the server, when they disconnect you can remove that name from the array, thus your array always contains the name of the users who are connected.

Comment: Yep. U gave me this idea with your answer. I didn't think of it but yes, that works fine ;) thanks a lot.

Comment: If it was the answer you were looking for please upvote and mark the answer as correct so it can help others too.

Comment: I am new ^^' I put your answer as correct but I cannot upvote it since I have less than 15 of reputation :/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
In fact I did something like your idea, sending a socket to get the username :
When a user gets connected he sends a 'new_user' socket,
the server broadcasts a 'new_user' socket,
every client detects the new user (to do some stuff) and sends an 'I am connected' socket',
the sever broadcast the username of every user connected.

At the end every users refresh their information about the poeple connected.

Thanks a lot,
Thomas